# jspm saying "github rate limit reached" - how to fix?

Tags: github, jspm

When I run `jspm install` to install JS dependencies in my Aurelia project, jspm says `Github rate limit reached`

How to fix?

Answer (score 38, accepted):

The rate limit can be lifted by configuring `jspm` with your Github credentials. To do this do the following:

1. Go to github.com, login and click `settings`
2. Click `Personal access tokens` and then `Generate new token`
3. Copy the token and start command line inside the project folder
4. Type `jspm registry config github`

During the config process, you will be asked to enter the token. Do so, and you're good to go.

[image: Configuring jspm to use a github token]

Comment: If running into this problem for Travis CI : solution here https://gist.github.com/topheman/25241e48a1b4f91ec6d4

Comment: Has anything changed to get around this without requiring that every single member of the team go through this process?  It is also problematic with a build server.  Whose account is it linked to, what if that person leaves, etc?  Looking into setting up a local repo/registry appears to be very involved (linking?) and not exactly maintenance friendly by all current or future devs on the team.

Comment: This looks like it is working on Heroku, I get stdout the same as you and I have set this `heroku config:set JSPM_GITHUB_AUTH_TOKEN` now I get an authorization message. Have tried ticking a few boxes in the github personal keys dialog too

Comment: This also works from the Azure Web App service control manager (i.e. from Kudu.)

Comment: See also https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/be7a70bd-a88b-4c47-9ac3-7883c48d2a9a/failure-attempting-to-github-deploy-a-node-application-to-azure-web-app?forum=azurescripting

Comment: I think you may also need to give the token the `public_repo` scope.

Comment: @DavidMartin Just run into the same problem. We set up a user `travis-<company-name>` for this sort of thing. Then use that to generate a token.