# Bundling looking for text.js in dist directory

Tags: systemjs, jspm, aurelia

Using the gulp tasks from the yeoman generated Aurelia app I'm trying to bundle a custom application. When I run `gulp bundle` the following error is reported.

[image]

Where can I find a log to help track down this file or the reference to this file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Double check your config.js

I've seen this from time to time, and it's usually an issue of the `config.js`. You'll want to make sure:

1. The `github`, `npm`, or wherever your text plugin is located is above your '*' line.
2. The text plugin is mapped.
3. The plugin files are located where (1) and (2) are pointing.

So, something like this:

**config.js**

```
  paths: {
    "github:*": "jspm_packages/github/*",
    "npm:*": "jspm_packages/npm/*",
    "*": "dist/*"
  },
  map: {
    "text": "github:systemjs/plugin-text@0.0.4"
  }
```

And `jspm_packages/github/systemjs/plugin-text@0.0.4` exists.

If all else fails, try deleting your jspm_packages folder, and typing `jspm install text`.

Comment: I think you're on to the right answer but this (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38679171/unauthorized-response-for-github-api-for-jspm-install) is preventing me from proceeding

Comment: I've added this plugin manually and can now bundle. Thanks for your help.

I still have the issue with the github credentials mentioned in the previous comment so I'll mark this one as answered.

Comment: I don't see the question, but have you tried this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30995040/jspm-saying-github-rate-limit-reached-how-to-fix

Comment: I deleted the question as I managed to get it working, thanks for the link